# Custom payment module form problem

Tags: commerce, 9

I'm a bit new to drupal and i'm trying to create custom payment gateway module and stuck with a problem. When creating OnSitePaymentGateway, everything is ok and i can edit checkout form with PaymentMethodAddForm. But for OffsitePaymentGatewayBase, I'm unable to output additional information to checkout form. This is the code I am using.

```php
/**
 * Provides the Cresh payment gateway.
 *
 * @CommercePaymentGateway(
 *   id = "creshio",
 *   label = "Cresh.io",
 *   display_label = "Cresh.io",
 *    forms = {
 *     "offsite-payment" = "Drupal\commerce_creshio\PluginForm\CreshioForm",
 *   },
 *
 *   js_library = "commerce_creshio/creshlib",
 * )
 */
class Creshio extends OffsitePaymentGatewayBase { .... }
```

Then I created CreshioForm.php in src/PluginForm/ and added following code.

```php
class CreshioForm extends BasePaymentOffsiteForm {

  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['#wrapper_id'] = Html::getUniqueId('payment-add-form-wrapper');
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="cresh-placeholder">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    return $form;
  }

}
```

I can't see cresh-placeholder in the form.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the broken markup and the browser is compensating? (You have an extra `</div>`)

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the comment, yep, that's a mistake, I've removed `</div>`, but that didn't help :(